# Looking to import selective data 'country-wise' from specific part of website into Google Spreadsheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import some data from [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm)'s website onto Google Spreadsheet / Excel. I tried using XCOPY method, but this page is constantly getting updated and the spreadsheet would eventually give 'N/A' error.

[image: googlesheets error]

I basically want a spreadsheet to import specific country's data into my sheet's cell(s). I am looking for it to be country-specific.

For example, I only want to import COSTA-RICA's data or CANADA's data from this website as shown below into my spreadsheet,

[image: Example]

Following is the spreadsheet link I'm editing : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1anrXXHuVtuP3iCDBsX8GcP7egDBmA75eeG4-wa1ov7E/edit#gid=1624254662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the whole list:

```
=INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div")),,1)
```

for canada use:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div")),,1), "limit "&
 MATCH("CAYMAN ISL.", INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div")),,1), 0)-
 MATCH("CANADA", INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div")),,1), 0)&" offset "&
 MATCH("CANADA", INDEX(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div")),,1), 0)-1, 0), "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image]

---

for costa rica change:

- `CANADA` to `COSTA RICA`
- `CAYMAN ISL.` to `COTE D'IVOIRE`

---

## UPDATE:

**full list:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♦"&TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[01]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[02]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[03]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[04]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[05]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[06]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[07]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[08]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[09]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[10]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[11]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[12]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[13]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[14]"))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦"))), "where Col1 is not null", 0))
```

**portion:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♦"&TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[01]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[02]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[03]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[04]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[05]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[06]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[07]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[08]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[09]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[10]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[11]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[12]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[13]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[14]"))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦"))), "where Col1 is not null", 0), "limit "&
 MATCH("PALAU",
 QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♦"&TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[01]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[02]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[03]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[04]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[05]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[06]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[07]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[08]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[09]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[10]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[11]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[12]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[13]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[14]"))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦"))), "where Col1 is not null", 0), 0)-
 MATCH("PAKISTAN",
 QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♦"&TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[01]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[02]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[03]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[04]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[05]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[06]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[07]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[08]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[09]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[10]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[11]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[12]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[13]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[14]"))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦"))), "where Col1 is not null", 0), 0)&" offset "&
 MATCH("PAKISTAN",
 QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♦"&TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 "//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[01]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[02]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[03]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[04]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[05]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[06]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[07]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[08]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[09]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[10]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[11]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[12]|
  //div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[13]|//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[14]"))
 ,,9^9)),,9^9), "♦"))), "where Col1 is not null", 0), 0)-1, 0))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dD5ETf4-2Sc-7z1EmcuquY7WqZury3jXqI1sQwkntL4/edit#gid=305564456)

---

**shorter formula:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♦"&TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 JOIN("|", "//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p["&ROW(A1:A15)&"]"))),,9^9)),,9^9), "♦"))), 
 "where Col1 !=''", 0), "limit "&
 MATCH("PALAU", QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♦"&TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 JOIN("|", "//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p["&ROW(A1:A15)&"]"))),,9^9)),,9^9), "♦"))),
 "where Col1 !=''", 0), 0)-
 MATCH("PAKISTAN", QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♦"&TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 JOIN("|", "//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p["&ROW(A1:A15)&"]"))),,9^9)),,9^9), "♦"))),
 "where Col1 !=''", 0), 0)&" offset "&
 MATCH("PAKISTAN", QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♦"&TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm", 
 JOIN("|", "//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p["&ROW(A1:A15)&"]"))),,9^9)),,9^9), "♦"))),
 "where Col1 !=''", 0), 0)-1, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @player0 for your help. It's working for **CANADA** and **COST RICA** However, when I change it to other country's names from list, it doesn't work. For example, when I change `CANADA` to `PAKISTAN` and `CAYMAN ISL.` to `PALAU`, it is unable to match it. I've also noticed that Country names with free cell spaces above them can be imported. Others without any free cells above them give 'N/A' error.

What changes do I have to make?

Comment: I'm using the exact same code above. Don't know what's wrong at my end.

(https://i.imgur.com/11EeLIR.png)

Comment: Thanks @player0

Now the only way I am able to import _PAKISTAN_'s data is if I change xpath_query from **"//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div"** to **"//div[@id='contentwrapper']//p[13]"**

Comment: @Tormenturator indeed, it cased to work... answer updated with a new approach

Comment: shorter answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F8nW.png - answer and the sheet updated

Comment: Thanks @player0 for the update. I've checked it just now and it's showing as 'N/A'. I've checked it using another internet connection and it's showing same result.

I think it's due to page getting updated on daily basis.

Comment: well looks like they keep changing the structure of the site

Comment: yes @player0

I'm currently using the following xpath queries for

Canada `//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/p` & Pakistan
`//div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div`

Answer (score 0):

XPath approach (one for country list, one for data for each country + 2 for specific countries) :
[image: iata]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_sKRvmsSxQ9tiU0aDOQc9wVxC2ZhMO8488jcKZVlN94/edit?usp=sharing

Final result is in the F column.